# Bash script to fix file names

Tags: files, rename

I have hundreds of folders with thousands subdirectories and files inside of them. The file names are currently in the format

`sf{number}-{number} - {text}`

and I need everything deleted until {text}.

Example:

```
sf012-05 - toto - africa.cdg 
sf012-05 - toto - africa.mp3
```

->

```
toto - africa.cdg
toto - africa.mp3
```

Additional formats:

```
SF-108 - 02 Johnny Hates Jazz Shattered Dreams[K].cdg
02 - David Essex - Rock On.cdg
SF0504 - 13 Walker Brothers, The  Make It Easy On Yourself.cdg
SFLY 051 - 07 America  A Horse With No Name.cdg
SF217-12 this love - maroon 5.cdg
SF262-13. Same Mistake - James Blunt.cdg
SF287 - 13 Luke Bryan Do I.cdg
SF355-01-15 - Tough Love - Pony.cdg
Track 11 Livin' La Vida Loca (Radio Edit) - Martin, Ricky.cdg
Sunfly Hits 275 - 07 SF275-7-Right Now (Na Na Na)-Akon.mp3
Second, Minute Or Hour - Jack Penate.mp3
SF057 - Karaoke Classics Vol.57 - 03 Abba Thank You For The Music.cdg
```

especially the last one is total crap.

That means I need a recursive regex bash script or something similar to go through these files and to rename them.

Comment: Please be more specific with an accual file name.

Comment: sf012-05 - toto - africa.cdg
sf012-05 - toto - africa.mp3

sf225-14 - duran duran - wild boys.cdg
sf225-14 - duran duran - wild boys.mp3

Comment: What happens if two different files have the same {text}?

Comment: Well two files are always going to have the same name since it's karaoke music, one is in cdg format and the other in mp3. they should all stay.

Comment: So in this case you want to remove `sf012-05 - ` and keep, say, `toto - africa.cdg`?

Comment: exactly. I use a Raspberry Pi with a small display and the prefix clutters the PyKaraoke window.

Comment: The format I first mentioned yes, however there are two more formats I found.

Comment: Unfortunately not, I added all formats I found now. A few songs are even named correctly.

Comment: Sounds like an impossible job. Your file names could be anything.

Comment: That's true. It would be enough for me to fix the sf/SF files though.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the Perl-based `rename` utility (called `prename` on some distributions) you can use a Regular Expression to rename all the files in one go.

Your requirement asks for the removal of `sf{number}-{number}` but all the examples start with capitals, some of them contain only one `{number}`, `{number}-{number}-{number}`, or even `{number}{space}-{space}{number}`. I'm going to assume that you want to include the first two of these cases.

```
rename -n 's/^sf[0-9-]+\s+(-\s+)?//' [Ss][Ff]*
```

Remove the `-n` when you are ready for it to apply its changes , or change it to `-v` to see it process files as it goes.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code (replace directory by the main directory, or where you have the subdirs):

```
cd directory
find -type f | while IFS= read - file; do 
    name=$(echo "$file"  | rev | cut -d'/' -f1 | rev |  cut -d'-' -f3- | cut -d' ' -f2-) 
    path=$(dirname "$file")  
    newname="${path}/${name}"
    echo mv "$file" "$newname" 
done
```

Where directory is the main directory where all the subdirectories is....

Please dont remove the "echo" from "mv", test it first.

Be carefully for not run that in the wrong dir, it can be very dangerous.

Comment: It returns "find: paths must precede expression: ."

Comment: Sorry Remove the '.'  from find and it will work.

Comment: I think the hyphen in the middle is not being removed. mv ./SF 003/sf003-03 - queen - bohemian rhapsody.cdg ./SF 003/03 - queen - bohemian rhapsody.cdg

Comment: Change -f2- to -f3-.  and see what happens. (updated the post)

Comment: Almost perfect, there's still a whitespace left after the directory though. ./SF 001/ seal - crazy.cdg

Comment: Add a new cut as my edit now | cut -d' ' -f2- (ups there is a hyphen on the end)

Comment: It is still wrong ?

Comment: It worked, thanks. However I found out that some one main directory has up to 3 different file formats, I added them to the main post. I'm not sure if touching them is a good idea. They are quite shitty songs anyway ;) I'll try out the script with echo.

Comment: This file will not work 01 - David Essex - Rock On.cdg , i need to think in a better solution, but im at work now.

Comment: Added even more. I think the best solution would be to find the first hyphen and delete everything up to the next letter after the hyphen. That should cover all formats.

Comment: It what we do in the first time, but dont work, because the second hyphen started the name of the files.....

Comment: I am mentally working in your case and i think it will not have a easy solution. Because your files dont have a default, if you want to automatize you need something that computer can recognize. What you see as default in your file names?

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do here with `cut` and `rev`.

Comment: I am getting the absolute name of the file, lets do this in your computer: echo "/usr/bin/bash" | rev | cut -d'/' -f1 | rev, it will returns just "bash". The last "/" is the first sentence to use as delimiter if the string is reverted.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest tool here would be [zsh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zsh) (like bash, only better), with its [fancy globbing](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Filename-Generation) and the [`zmv` function](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/User-Contributions.html#index-zmv). Run this from the toplevel directory where you want to rename files.

```
autoload -U zmv
zmv '(**/)[Ss][Ff][0-9]##-[0-9]##[- ]#(*)' '$1$2'
```

Explanation: `**/` is any string of leading directories. Then there's a pattern of `sf` (case-insensitive) followed by one or more digits, a dash and another number, followed by dashes and spaces. Finally there can be any suffix `*`. The numbers in the replacement refer to the parenthesized groups in the pattern.

---

Alternatively, you can use `prename` (the Perl-based rename script, available on Debian and Arch Linux, might need to be installed separately on other distributions). You'll need to combine it with `find` to gather the list of files to rename. It doesn't matter if `rename` is passed non-matching files, it'll skip files for which there's no renaming to be done.

```
find -name '[Ss][Ff]*' -exec prename 's!/!sf[0-9]+-[0-9]+[- ]*!!i' {} +
```

Answer (score 0):

You say you *need everything deleted until {text}*, but your example doesn't show that.  Rather than showing exact code, let me just suggest a plan.

1) Write a script that does what you want for *one* filename. Something like this might do:

```
#! /bin/sh
test -d ~/OK/${PWD} || mkdir -p ~/OK/${PWD}
ln "$1" "~/OK/${PWD}/$1"
echo "$1" | awk -F ' - ' '{print $NF}'
```

That breaks the name on the pattern ' - ' and prints the last field.  And saves the original filename so you can retrieve it if something goes wrong. Test it a few times, and use `mv` to restore the names.

2) Invoke your script with **find**:

```
$ find dirname -exec script.awk {} +
```

That will bury your machine with many parallel invocations of your script.  When it's done, you'll have a bunch of OK directories to remove, and you'll know how to use find to remove them.